# java try catch finally - return

Tags: java

Trying out a try catch finally use case -

```
public class Finallyy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = method1();
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static int method1() {
        int a = 2;
        try {
            int b = 0;
            a = a / a;
            System.out.println("try");
            return a;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("caught");
            a = 5;
            return a;
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("finally");
            a = 10;
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
try

finally

10
```

> **If the code is modified to**

```
finally {
            System.out.println("finally");
            a = 10;
            //return a;
        }
```

**Output:**

```
try

finally

1
```

**Question** - Is there some concept of stack where the '`return a`' in `try` block is stored [*if the example is altered, then it applies to try or catch block*], and popped when control leaves the `method1()` only in the absence of a  '`return`' in `finally` block ?

**Update: Solution concluded:**

When the return statement is executed, the value to be returned is stored. When the finally block completes, that value is returned.

The finally block gets always executed as last. So the return in the finally block OVERWRITES the other returns in the try/catch blocks. It's a very bad practice to return or throw an exception from the finally block for this reason.

So to the original question - is it only in the absence of a  '`return`' in `finally` block ? NO. It doesn't matter.

**Edit:**

This question is asked on Apr 8 and is answered already. The question that is currently marked along with this as duplicate, is one asked at a later date [August 15]. Hence the new question is to be marked as duplicate, and not this one. However sharing the referenc eto a similar question is good.

Comment: Yes.  Your "some concept of stack" is the stack.

Comment: @DavidWallace, you mean the value of a is stored in the stack? I mean the value is stored in stack memory as any other values inside a function is stored?

Comment: Yes.  The method that you've called puts its return value on the stack.  The calling method pops it off.

Comment: @DavidWallace , Although this is not related to my original question... you said "The calling method pops it off". Is it the calling method, or .. the current method, before actually returning the value to the calling function, pops it off the stack and return the value to the calling function?

Comment: The mechanism for returning a value from any method is that the callee pushes the value to the stack, and the caller pops it off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `try` block is executed before its `finally` block.

When the `return` statement is executed, the value to be returned is stored. When the `finally` block completes, that value is returned.

Note that `a` is not a value. `a` is a variable that stores a value. If you change `a`, you change `a`, you don't change the value that was stored for the `return`.

For the technical reason, we go to the [Java Language Specification on the `try-finally` block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2)

> If execution of the try block completes abruptly for any other reason
>   R, then the finally block is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
> - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason R.
> - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (**and reason R is discarded**).

[A `return` statement completes **abruptly**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21), so if a `try` with a `finally` has a `return` and the `finally` also has a `return`, the `finally`'s `return` supersedes the `try`'s.

Answer (score 1):

The finally block gets always executed as last. So the return in the finally block OVERWRITES the other returns in the try/catch blocks. 
It's a very bad practice to return or throw an exception from the finally block for this reason.

Nothing to do with stacks: it's a matter of the fact that the finally block gets always executed as last block, so what is returned or thrown in the finally block erases and overwrites any previous exit value (returned object or exception thrown).

Try this:

```
try {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
finally {
    return 0;
}
```

The `return` in the finally block will overwrite (swallow) the NullPointerException...

Comment: thanks.. I understand it is bad practice to return something in finally and even the compiler gives a warning  "finally block does not complete normally" meaning it is not  'advicable' to return anything from finally. It was for the example to express my question

Comment: I choose the other one as answer as it answered many aspects of my question. Thank you too

Answer (score 0):

A try..catch..finally is actually compiled as a nested try..catch (of the exception you specify) within a try..catch (of "any"), and the "finally" block is cut & pasted by the compiler to the "end" of each code path. (I put "end" in quotes because I can't remember off the top of my head how it handles multiple exits from a "try" or "catch" block.) You can use the javap command (dis-assembler) to experiment on what byte code is generated by your version of Java to correspond to different try..catch..finally combinations.